# How to read xml string values using this path as shown in code(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+ File.separator + "test.xml")

Tags: java, android, xml

Hi Everybody,

I am new to Android. I am using DOM parsing for reading xml string value. For that, I used following code, that code will work up to getting root element value after that it is giving exception please solve this problem,

Advance Thanks,

### Xml Code:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<ChangePassword>
  <Oldpassword>23545565635354</Oldpassword>
  <Newpassword>addsffggfdsfdsfdfs </Newpassword>
</ChangePassword>
```

### java code:

```
   File file = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+ File.separator + "test.xml"); DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                      DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                      Document doc = db.parse(file);
                      doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
                      System.out.println("Root element " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
                      NodeList nodeLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("ChangePassword");
                      System.out.println("Information of all entries");

                      for (int s = 0; s < nodeLst.getLength(); s++) {

                        Node fstNode = nodeLst.item(s); 

                        if (fstNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                        {
                          Element fstElmnt = (Element) fstNode;

                          // Firstname
                          NodeList fstNmElmntLst = ((Document) fstElmnt).getElementsByTagName("Oldpassword");
                          Element fstNmElmnt = (Element) fstNmElmntLst.item(0);
                          NodeList fstNm = ((Node) fstNmElmnt).getChildNodes();
                          System.out.println("Old password : "  + ((Node) fstNm.item(0)).getNodeValue());

                          // Lastname
                          NodeList lstNmElmntLst = ((Document) fstElmnt).getElementsByTagName("Newpassword");
                          Element lstNmElmnt = (Element) lstNmElmntLst.item(0);
                          NodeList lstNm = ((Node) lstNmElmnt).getChildNodes();
                          System.out.println("Old password : " + ((Node) lstNm.item(0)).getNodeValue());

                          // Address
                          NodeList addrNmElmntLst = ((Document) fstElmnt).getElementsByTagName("Newpassword");
                          Element addrNmElmnt = (Element) addrNmElmntLst.item(0);
                          NodeList addrNm = ((Node) addrNmElmnt).getChildNodes();
                          System.out.println("Address : " + ((Node) addrNm.item(0)).getNodeValue());
                        }
                      }
                  } catch (Exception e) {
                      Log.e("Exception",e.toString());
                    //e.printStackTrace();
                  }
```

Comment: Standard comments: (42a) *what exception* and (42b) *where (line of code)* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Document doc = db.parse(in);
Element docElem = doc.getDocumentElement();
NodeList nl = docElem.getElementsByTagName("Oldpassword");
```

try that...

**update**
maybe it would be helpful if you take a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.asp

the following code is working, is just tested.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;


public class testxml {

private String filepath = "src/xml.xml";

public void parse() {

    File file = new File(filepath);

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db;
    try {
        db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(file);

        Element docElem = doc.getDocumentElement();
        NodeList nl1 = docElem.getElementsByTagName("Oldpassword");

        for(int i = 0; i < nl1.getLength(); i++) {
            Element entry = (Element)nl1.item(i);
            System.out.println(entry.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
        }

        NodeList nl2 = docElem.getElementsByTagName("Newpassword");

        for(int i = 0; i < nl2.getLength(); i++) {
            Element entry = (Element)nl2.item(i);
            System.out.println(entry.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
        }

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    testxml x = new testxml();
    x.parse();

}
```

}

Comment: if i paste this code it is showing errors like casting at this stage   NodeList nl1 = docElem.getElementsByTagName("Oldpassword"); after that i used casting even though it is firing same exception  can you please check and let me know

Comment: Please show me what part you copied (how your code looks like), because it is still working in my case. No need to check again. `getElementsByTagName` returns a `Nodelist`, so no idea why you have casting errors. Please update your post on the top with your current code, show the error message too.

Answer (score 2):

Wow. The DOM Parser code is pretty ugly. Please just [try Simple XML instead](http://simple.sourceforge.net/). Look at what your code could be like:

```
@Root(name = "ChangePassword")
public class PasswordChange {
   @Element(name = "Oldpassword")
   public String oldPassword;

   @Element(name = "Newpassword")
   public String newPassword;
}
```

And that is much nicer. And then you can just say:

```
Serializer serial = new Persister();
PasswordChange pc = serial.read(PasswordChange.class, streamOrFileWithXML);
```

And that is all that there is to it. Though if you want to see how to include it in Android have a [look at my blog post](http://robertmassaioli.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/simple-xml-in-android-1-5-and-up/).

Comment: i did above chnges even though it is giving excepton at creating object to element please help me,

Comment: Create a new stack overflow question for the error that you are getting. Then point me to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line

```
NodeList nodeLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("ChangePassword");
```

To this

```
NodeList nodeLst = doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("ChangePassword");
```

If not, show us your stack trace.

Comment: iam getting same exception please help me,